# How to avoid AlertDialogs overlapping each other?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a series of events in my app that can cause multiple `AlertDialog` to show, but they will overlap each other so that the newest one will be on top.

How can I make the `AlertDialog` boxes wait their turn to show only after the user dismisses the previous one?

Comment: when the user taps yes or no just show the other.....like this go on..

Comment: they are triggered by different logics so a set of combinations can cause some to overlap

Answer (score 0):

It is possible..
If your flow for various event response is fix then you can do it like

First Alert Dialog builder :

```
.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) { 

            //whatever you want for positive response from user
            //open next alert dialg
            nextDialog();  

            }  
        })  
.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {  
            //  Action for 'NO' Button  
            dialog.dismiss();  

            //whatever you want for positive response from user
            //open next alert dialg
            nextDialog(); 
         }
```

and in next alert dialog builder you can open other alert dialog as per your requirement.

Comment if you need clarification.

*Happy coding...*

Comment: No, the flow is not fixed. There are different events that can trigger the Dialogs and sometimes they overlap.

Comment: thank you for this answer, but OP should indicate this to clarify the question please. I have this same question